# SQL MYSQL Mult-Table Query Join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Ok, I never post on here until I've spent days trying to figure it
out on my own.

This one is extremely tough.  I will be very suprised and
also in awe of anyone who solves this one.

ALSO NOTE:  I am doing this in PHP and don't care how many queries or loops
I need to make to accomplish this ..  so if more than one query or a php loop can
help then by all means please suggest it.  Thanks

UPDATE:  To simplify this,  if you can solve it with availMetals like %White Gold%  insetad of like %catFilter.value% I think it will be easier.

I can use PHP loops to accomplish the rest.

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to look.

I have 3 tables with the following fields:

```
catFilter - (id, catTypeId, value)
products - (id, availMetals)
prodFilter - (id, catFilterId, productId)
```

And the following Relations

```
products.id = prodFilter.productId
catFilter.id = prodFilter.catFilterId
```

I need to get three pieces of data as the
ultimate result:

```
catFilter.id (also could be prodFilter.catFilterId)
catFilter.value
```

So far I can get those two...  I need the third..

```
A COUNT OF ..  All Products who have an availMetals like
of %White Gold% and also has catTypeId = 1
```

Here is What the final list would Look Like ...

catFilter.value - Product Count

```
classic - 0
rings - 0
sets - 1
stones - 5
three - 0
halo - 3
```

etc.. etc...

Here is some sample data for the tables

```
products

id - availMetals
111 - White Gold
112 - White Gold, Yellow Gold
113 - White Gold
114 - White Gold
115 - White Gold
116 - White Gold, Platinum, Palladium


prodFilter

productId - catFilterId
111 - 43
111 - 12
111 - 48
111 - 47
112 - 12
112 - 51
112 - 48
113 - 12
113 - 51
113 - 48
114 - 12
114 - 51
114 - 48
115 - 12
115 - 48
116 - 12
116 - 51

catFilter
id - catTypeId - value
1 - 1 - Classic
50 - 1 - Rings
47 - 1 - Sets
48 - 1 - Stones
49 - 1 - Three
51 - 1 - Halo
```

Comment: What is the link between your table product with the others ? Do the id field in this table corresponds to the id in a another table ?

Comment: Yes,  product.id = prodFilter.productId  and  catFilter.id = prodFilter.catFilterId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like :

```
SELECT cf.id, cf.value, COUNT(p.id)
FROM catFilter cf
INNER JOIN prodFilter pf ON pf.catFilterId = cf.id
INNER JOIN products p ON p.id = productId
WHERE cf.catTypeId = 1 AND p.availMetals LIKE CONCAT('%', cf.value, '%')
GROUP BY cf.id
```

Comment: sorry just getting a 1 row result of 0

Comment: empty result... is there i can do this with multiple queries .. or using php scripting loop?

Comment: When I do this using "White Gold" as the cf.value, I get a count, but the results are incorrect.. I get 4 halo, not 3 .. wait.. should it be 4 ?  im so brain fried

Answer (score 1):

I've use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`so that it will return zero in count if it does not exist in `products` table. try this one:

<del>SELECT
    a.ID,
    a.`Value`,
    COUNT(c.*) as ProductCount
FROM catFilter a LEFT JOIN prodFilter b ON
        a.catTypeID = b.catFilterID
    LEFT JOIN products c ON
        b.productID = c.ID
WHERE c.availMetals like CONCAT('%', a.`Value`, '%') AND 
      a.catTypeId = 1
GROUP BY a.ID</del>

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT 
    c.`Value`,
    COUNT(*) as TotalCount
FROM Products a LEFT JOIN prodFIlter b on
        a.ID = b.ProductID
    LEFT JOIN catFilter c
        b.CatFilterID = c.ID
WHERE c.CatTypeID = 1 and 
      a.availmetals like CONCAT('%', 'White GOld','%')
GROUP BY c.`Value`
```

Comment: did you change `'PLACEVALUEHERE'` to `a.Value`?

Comment: I can probably use this to create some kind of loop in php, but as a stand alone query its still giving me empty result

Comment: hmm, can you provide dummy records for the three tables? thanks.

Comment: added sample data plus sample results

Answer (score 1):

Does this make the trick?

```
select cf.id, cf.value,
  sum(if(cf.catTypeId = 1 and p.availMetals like concat('%', cf.value, '%')
  = 1, 1, 0)) as FinalCount
from catFilter cf
join prodFilter pf on cf.id = pf.catFilterId
join products p on pf.productId = p.id
group by cf.id, cf.value
```

**Edit:**

According to the provided data, nothing should match, right? Because `p.availMetals like concat('%', cf.value, '%')` is always false. Let's force it. Change this record:

```
prodFilter
productId | catFilterId
111       | 43
```

To this one:

```
catFilter
id | catTypeId | value
1  | 1         | Classic
```

And change this one:

```
catFilter
id | catTypeId | value
1  | 1         | Gold
```

That way, you'll have a match and will be displayed by the query. So far it is a data issue.

**Edit 2**

From the given data there can't be 3 Halo matches:

```
products
id - availMetals
111 - White Gold
112 - White Gold, Yellow Gold <-- Will look here and won't match!
113 - White Gold <-- Will look here and won't match!
114 - White Gold <-- Will look here and won't match!
115 - White Gold
116 - White Gold, Platinum, Palladium <-- Will look here and won't match!
```

Not to mention the selected answer will not provide `classic - 0` nor any group with 0 results.

Comment: This is the closest thing I've seen yet,  everything is good except the "counts" are all 0

Comment: Are you sure? I'm getting results here. Can you check some of the rows by hand and see why is that? Maybe you're missing data or you don't really have catTypeId = 1 and availMetals like %cf.value%. In case you DO have a row fulfilling that condition, can you provide the data that is not matching so that I can add it to my test data? Thanks

Comment: added the data ive been using

Comment: again, if multiple queries or php .loops would help, im open to that

Comment: and instead of availMetals like %value%, lets just try to get it to work wtih "White Gold"

Comment: You make a very good point,  and with the updated requirements of just getting White Gold to work, your answer works as well, I gave the answer to the guy who answered first that worked with the new scenario,  don't know if thats fair, but he does have a lot less pts than you so I figure he could use em more than you could.  Eitherway,  Thx much for you time and everyone elses.

Comment: Don't mind the points. It's enough for me just to not sound that crazy about not getting results :)

Answer (score 1):

Right, let's try step-by-step:

```
SELECT * FROM catFilter
LEFT JOIN prodFilter ON catFilter.id = prodFilter.catFilterId
LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = prodFilter.productId
```

The above, based on your described relationships, would return all data that exists in the tables joined into one relation. Because we use LEFT JOIN, we will also get the catFilters that are not used in any products.

Now, to add the conditions you mention, let's add the where condition:

```
WHERE availMetals LIKE '%White Gold%' AND catTypeId = 1
```

Now, you want the results to be aggregated by CatFilter value, so let's add a grouping condition:

```
GROUP BY catFilter.value
```

And now, let's just select the counts / fields needed:

```
SELECT catFilter.id, catFilter.value, count(catFilter.id) FROM catFilter
LEFT JOIN prodFilter ON catFilter.id = prodFilter.catFilterId
LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = prodFilter.productId
WHERE availMetals LIKE '%White Gold%' AND catTypeId = 1
GROUP BY catFilter.value
```